# how to modify .sql file with ruby?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I generated a .sql file by mysqldump command:

```
system "mysqldump -u#{USERNAME} --password=#{PASSPORT} --extended-insert #{DATABASE} #{table_name} > init_#{table_name}.sql"
```

the .sql file looks like this:

```
.....
.....
LOCK TABLES `config_products` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `config_products` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `config_products` VALUES (1,1000,30,54),(2,2000,30,56),(3,3000,30,51)，(4,1000,30,54)....
.....
.....
```

All the data is merged into one line, but i want it looks like it:

```
.....
.....
LOCK TABLES `config_products` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `config_products` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `config_products` VALUES
    (1,1000,30,54),
    (2,2000,30,56),
    (3,3000,30,51)，
    (4,1000,30,54)....
.....
.....
```

Is there any easy way to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsub`, and replace opening bracket using a `newline`, a `tab` and the bracket itself.

You should either do this before writing or on reading

```
text = "INSERT INTO `config_products` VALUES (1,1000,30,54),(2,2000,30,56),(3,3000,30,51)，(4,1000,30,54)...."

newtext = text.gsub(/\(/,"\n\t(")
#INSERT INTO `config_products` VALUES 
#        (1,1000,30,54),
#        (2,2000,30,56),
#        (3,3000,30,51)，
#        (4,1000,30,54)....
```

**UPDATE**
Since this is done with a system task, you can do this, in ruby console, or write a helper method somewhere, if you are going to use this a lot.

```
def export_formatted_sql(DATABASE,table_name,USERNAME,PASSWORD)
    system "mysqldump -u#{USERNAME} --password=#{PASSPORT} --extended-insert #{DATABASE} #{table_name} > init_#{table_name}.sql"
    file    = File.open("init_#{table_name}.sql","r")
    newtext = file.read.gsub(/\(/,"\n\t(")
    file.close
    file    = File.open("init_#{table_name}.sql","w") # overwrite the existing file
    file.write newtext
    file.close
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this gem once, may be helpful to you:

`anbt-sql-formatter`

Answer (score 0):

I found a easy way to make it. We can get the target file directly by "sed" command.

```
system "mysqldump -u#{USERNAME} --password=#{PASSPORT} --extended-insert #{DATABASE} #{table_name} | sed 's/),/),\\'$'\\n/g'  > init_#{table_name}.sql"
```